# Adding LibTorch-Lite to SPM framework

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, libtorch

I have an XCFramework that utilizes LibTorch-Lite, OpenCV, and LASwift from CocoaPods.
I would like to import the XCFramework to Swift Package Manager (SPM). I managed to find packages for OpenCV and LASwift, but not for LibTorch-Lite. As far as I understand, there isn't an existing package for it. I tried adding it using CocoaPods and excluding arm64, but it caused issues with SwiftUI preview. My question is there any way for me to add the LibTorch-Lite library without having to do it locally?